# number of select and update queries for benchmarks?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, jdbc, benchmarking

I don’t really understand why 30 000 objects need 3000 selects and 3000 updates, do you think that these numbers are arbitrary? Ie. Could they have used 30 000 selects and 30 000 updates?

[image]

I found this at http://polepos.sourceforge.net/results/PolePositionClientServer.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, the objective behind choosing a number while doing benchmarking is a rather big number . It has an advantage that a program will execute for a measurable amount of time. If the number is too slow like 100 updates then the execution time will  be in mili seconds and will be extremely difficult to bench mark them.

Comment: BTW .. what was the point of asking this ? Are you trying to conduct your own benchmarks ?

Comment: I'm trying to compare performance of jdbc vs hibernate... I'll be doing my own benchmarks too for jdbc...

Comment: I have done the same some time back. Some tips for doing benchmark between hibernate and jdbc :-  1. You will feel the difference if you are running complex queries having Joins & inner queries 2. Hibernate starts having all sorts of problems when the number of objects increase in memory . So you need to keep control on the environment . 3. Because of the above 2 points, the optimum use of either will work at different environment settings and for different     designs.                                                                     Let us know the output of your test. Good Luck !!!